# Did new Date().getTime() returns utc milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

new Date().getTime() // returns same utc milliseconds for all system time zones

So, is new Date().getTime() returns utc milliseconds?

Comment: Yes. _The `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds* since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)_ - [`Date.prototype.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: Is  number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch equal to UTC milliseconds?

Comment: If you read the link it also says. _"getTime() always uses UTC for time representation"_

Comment: @RSMoorthi Unix timestamp is ***always*** in UTC. Therefore, a Unix timestamp in milliseconds is also in UTC.

Comment: Thanks both of you

Comment: I would encourage you to [do a bit more research yourself before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on Stack Overflow. If you want to know what `.getTime()` returns, check the documentation of `.getTime()` (also linked by evolutionxbox). It tells you exactly what you want to know. Also note that asking too many ill-received questions will trigger an automated [question-ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: Tip: use [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) instead of `new Date().getTime()`. It shorter and cleaner.

Comment: @VLAZ The Unix timestamp has nothing to do with UTC. It's the amount of time (seconds or milliseconds) since Unix Epoch. Which is `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`, but you could just as well say it is `1970-01-01 01:00:00 CET` (+1) or `1969-12-31 19:00:00 EST` (-5). The only thing it has to do with UTC is that the Unix Epoch is easiest to remember in UTC.

Comment: @3limin4t0r no, you're wrong. The Unix timestamp is meaningless if you decide to key it off any other timezone. What would `1000` in milliseconds be? Would it be one second after midnight or one second after two o'clock in the morning? If you involve *other* time zones it becomes ambiguous. Yet it isn't, it's *always* 1 second after midnight on the 1st of January 1970 ***in the UTC time zone***. It's otherwise *impossible* to resolve the ambiguity if you take any other time zone into consideration.

Comment: @VLAZ That is where you are wrong. It is 1 second after midnight in UTC, but it's also 1 second after 1 o'clock in Europe with CET. Both are happening at the same moment in time. - If I execute `new Date(1000)` in JavaScript it also converts it to my local time zone and gives me `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:01 GMT+0100`

Comment: @3limin4t0r that is correct. But Unix timestamp is defined in relation to midnight UTC. Not midnight Europe. Nor midnight in Chine, nor midnight in any other time zone. Nor is it defined as 1 o'clock in CET, nor 8 o'clock Beijing time or anything else. . Your suggestion was that there was no relation to UTC and it was just "easier to remember". False, there is a very strong relation to UTC as it's the driving definition. You're welcome to provide reference about Unix timestamp completely divorced from UTC if you believe that to be the case.

Comment: @VLAZ It might be defined in UTC, but a millisecond is just a millisecond. The distance in time from a specific point does not need a time zone, the specific point does need one. If I say I'll have to go in 5 minutes, it doesn't matter what time zone I'm in.  "now" might be 2022-02-03 18:00 for me and 2022-02-03 11:00 for you. With both call the reference point 0 and add 5 minutes. The 5 minutes are not bound by time zone, only the reference point is. Coming back to time since Unix Apoch, the seconds (or milliseconds) do NOT have a time zone, only the reference point has.

Comment: @3limin4t0r and it's the reference point is defined in UTC.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes. So your answer to *"Is number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch equal to UTC milliseconds?"* Is incorrect. Unix Epoch is defined in UTC, but *"number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch"* are not "UTC milliseconds" they are just milliseconds. The duration of 1 millisecond is fixed regardless of the time zone you're working with.

Comment: @VLAZ "*and it's the reference point is defined in UTC*" - not even that. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) has some interesting insights, both that the original definition didn't specify a timezone at all and that the UTC we're using today is no longer the same UTC as on 1 January 1970. Really, it doesn't matter in what terms we define the epoch, only that we can agree on the same instant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such things as "UTC milliseconds". A millisecond is an [SI unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Prefixes) that is one thousandth of a second.

ECMAScript Date instances hold a time value that is an offset in milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (the ECMAScript epoch). As a consequence, *Dates* are considered to be UTC, but that's just a concept based on the underlying time value.